# Merging and/or Reading 88 JSON Files into Dataframe - different datatypes

Tags: json, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I basically have a procedure where I make multiple calls to an API and using a token within the JSON return pass that pack to a function top call the API again to get a "paginated" file.

In total I have to call and download 88 JSON files that total 758mb. The JSON files are all formatted the same way and have the same "schema" or at least should do. I have tried reading each JSON file after it has been downloaded into a data frame, and then attempted to union that dataframe to a master dataframe so essentially I'll have one big data frame with all 88 JSON files read into.

However the problem I encounter is roughly on file 66 the system (Python/Databricks/Spark) decides to change the file type of a field. It is always a `string` and then I'm guessing when a value actually appears in that field it changes to a `boolean`. The problem is then that the unionbyName fails because of different datatypes.

What is the best way for me to resolve this? I thought about reading using "extend" to merge all the JSON files into one big file however a 758mb JSON file would be a huge read and undertaking.

Could the other solution be to explicitly set the schema that the JSON file is read into so that it is always the same type?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the attributes of those files, you can define the schema before reading them and create an empty df with that schema so you can to a `unionByName` with the `allowMissingColumns=True`:

something like:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

my_schema = StructType([
                            StructField('file_name',StringType(),True),
                            StructField('id',LongType(),True),
                            StructField('dataset_name',StringType(),True),
                            StructField('snapshotdate',TimestampType(),True)
                              ])

output = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), my_schema)

df_json = spark.read.[...your JSON file...]

output.unionByName(df_json, allowMissingColumns=True)
```

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for. I hope it helps

Comment: Hi Luiz, thanks for the response. The schema for my JSON file in question is massive. If I set the schema will it only the corresponding referenced "names" from my JSON into the relevant ones in the dataframe? Additionally will it error if I set my schema for the DF as say "string" and spark.read.json decides the field is a Boolean for example? Or will it convert it?

Comment: I did not understand this-> "If I set the schema will it only the corresponding referenced "names" from my JSON into the relevant ones in the dataframe". Aren't the 88 JSONs with the same schema? If the files have the same schema and you union them, the union will result in the same schema, right? So you can define the schema for your big df and for each single JSON file you read. That way, spark will not try to guess the type of each column (this is call schema inferring)

Comment: spark.read.schema(my_schema).load('my_path/my_JSON.json')

Comment: Hi Luiz, Schema Inferring was what I meant by my horrible sentence. You are on the money. OK I'll have to give it a go.